# bootstrap Navbar V.S. HTML ul li

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing a online shopping website of my work,

and I use `<ul>` `<li>` and `<a>` to acheive that.

I just want to know how's different between the bootstrap Navbar and HTML ul li.

And want to know which is the better choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap Navbar also uses `<ul><li>`. It is simply styled with the Bootstrap classes, while you would have to style it yourself if you write your own HTML `<ul><li>` navbar

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is very similar, just a bit easier and fits different screens better, however it still uses the `<ul>` and `<li>` format.